# Excel - Highlight a cell using conditional formatting based on other cells that are highlighted

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on a report and I need to figure out how to use conditional formatting to highlight a name when the data in the same row is highlighted more than 3 times.

Ex.
[Example of what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8HY1.png)

I want to see if I can highlight the name based on the number of times there is highlighted data in the row. I have conditional formatting to highlight data that is less than 4 and I would like to have John's name highlight since he has been under 4, 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting that applies to column A     In your conditional format dialog box, enter a formula condition for

```
COUNTIF(1:1,4)>3
```

Note that there are no absolute reference.